# MySQL SSL setup failure

Tags: mysql, ssl, openssl

I am following word by word of http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/creating-ssl-certs.html for creating SSL certificates to setup SSL enable replication but it is not working for me. Steps which I am following:

1. Using above reference I have created all required certificates in
   /var/opt/mysql_certs/
2. changed the ownership of all the certificates
       chown -R mysql:mysql /var/opt/mysql_certs
3. Then I have edited my /etc/my.conf and put these 3 lines in mysqld section:
       ssl-ca=/var/opt/mysql_certs/ca-cert.pem
       ssl-cert=/var/opt/mysql_certs/server-cert.pem
       ssl-key=/var/opt/mysql_certs/server-key.pem
4. Lastly I am restarting mysqld with /etc/init.d/restart mysqld. But, I am getting following errors:
    [Warning] Failed to setup SSL
    [Warning] SSL error: SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed

FYI: OS is centOS 6.5

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](http://dba.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Comment: This was some weird issue which got fixed automatically once I put ssl certificates into /var/lib/mysql/

Comment: @nirprat If it was fixed when you put ssl certs into /var/lib/mysql , it was probably related to selinux denying access to files outside of that directory. Check the selinux logs and you should see a denial message when you restart MySQL. Also see https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/91514/mysql-ssl-setup-failed