# PHP server on cpanel hosting cannot locate SSL certificates to connect to remote MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, ssl

I have a PHP script on godaddy cPanel hosting to create a connection to a remote MySQL with SSL certificates. i have placed my certificates in the right path which is `/etc/mysql/ssl/` but unfortunately i am getting this error

> Warning: mysqli_real_connect(): (HY000/2026): SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed in /home/shandonjoe/public_html/fingerprint/connect.php on line 10
>   Connect error (2026): SSL connection error: SSL_CTX_set_default_verify_paths failed

This is my codes

```
 <?php
    ini_set ('error_reporting', E_ALL);
    ini_set ('display_errors', '1');
    error_reporting (E_ALL|E_STRICT);
    $db = mysqli_init();
    mysqli_options ($db, MYSQLI_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT, true);
    $db->ssl_set('/etc/mysql/ssl/client-key.pem', 
    '/etc/mysql/ssl/client-
    cert.pem', '/etc/mysql/ssl/ca-cert.pem', NULL, NULL);
    $link = mysqli_real_connect ($db, 'ip', 'username', 'password', 
    'dbname', 3306, NULL, MYSQLI_CLIENT_SSL);
    if (!$link)
    {
      die ('Connect error (' . mysqli_connect_errno() . '): ' . 
      mysqli_connect_error() . "\n");
    } else {
    $res = $db->query('SHOW TABLES;');
    print_r ($res);
    $db->close();
    }
?>
```

Comment: This question is better suited for the Tech support from your host.

Comment: you should really not be having to do any of this........ not once of my ssl installations have I had to configure mysql to read it, nor would I use any ini_sets (other than the errors one) in a script..

Comment: Agree with @FMashiro - but did find this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28409764/mysql-ssl-setup-failure Good luck.